# SwiftUI - Detect tap on TabView to scroll to the top of the list

Tags: swift, swiftui-list, swiftui

I want to get the instagram or twitter style of when you click on the current tab item, scroll up. 
In UIKit it is simple, but here I can't get the .onTapGesture method to be called in the tabItem.

Comment: The duplicate doesn't answer the question. Voting to re-open.